# If then else or if then elseif vba?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to add the following logic to a macro in Excel from a SQL proc and am having trouble converting it:

```
CASE WHEN Dept < '600' THEN '0' + convert(varchar,RTRIM(Dept)) 
when Dept between '650' and '899'  THEN convert(varchar,RTRIM(Dept)) + '0'
ELSE convert(varchar,RTRIM(Dept)) + '0' END As Dept_Num
```

The display I desire is this:

- If the Dept number in Table1[DEPT1] is between 0 and 599, then add a
  leading zero, aka 001 becomes 0001.
- If the Dept number in Table1[DEPT1] is between 650 and 899, then add
  a following zero, aka 650 becomes 6500.
- If the Dept number in Table1[DEPT1] is any other number, add a
  following zero, aka 600 becomes 6000.

  ```
  Dim deptnum As Integer, result As String
  deptnum = Range("Table1[Dept1]").Value
  If deptnum < 600 Then deptnum = Left(Range("Table1[Dept1]") & "0000", 4)
  Ifelse deptnum = Right(Range("Table1[Dept1]") & "0000", 4)
  ```

As you can see, I am struggling with the concept of multiple conditions and this is my first time writing a statement like this...any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is this VBA meant to do? Will it go through every value in a table and put out the corresponding values somewhere? Is result the output or do you need it for something?

Comment: Yes, I want it to go through every value in the column "Dept1" and add either a prefix or suffix zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim varcell as Variant

For Each varcell in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeptData").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange
   If varcell.value < 600 Then
      varcell.value = "0" & cstr(varcell.value)
   Else
      varcell.value = cstr(varcell.value) & "0"
   End If
Next
```

Please note that we need to update the points where the ' is.

Comment: Dim varcell As Variant

For Each varcell In ThisWorkbook. _
Sheets(DeptData). _
ListObjects(1). _
ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange
I get a run-time error '9', subscript out of range error. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Testdeptnum()

Dim deptnum As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim deptrng As Range
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set deptrng = SourceSheet.Range("DEPT1")
For Each c In deptrng.Cells
    If c.Value < 600 Then
        deptnum = c.Value
        result = "0" & deptnum
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).NumberFormat = "00##"
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = result
    ElseIf c.Value > 650 And c.Value < 899 Then
        deptnum = c.Value
        result = deptnum & "0"
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).NumberFormat = "00##"
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = result
    Else
        deptnum = c.Value
        result = deptnum & "0"
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).NumberFormat = "00##"
        SourceSheet.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = result
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I'm not entirely sure what the format of your Table1 data is in thus I can't really be sure what format it needs to be targeting, etc.

The gist of it is this: you need to iterate through the cells, not the range. The range.value can't return a value for each cell, it will return a single value. In order to evaluate the individual value of each cell in a range, you have to step through the range in a loop (I used a For Each).

Keep in mind, your results may vary depending on what format your workbook/data is in. Here my "Table1" is assumed to be a Worksheet named "Data" which you can replace as you need to. If Table1 is your workbook or file name, you don't need to include it at all unless you also interact with another file/workbook within your same function/module.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're just missing a few keywords. Also, formatting this in the below manner will make this more obvious:

```
Dim deptnum As Integer, result As String
deptnum = Range("Table1[Dept1]").Value
If deptnum < 600 Then 
    deptnum = Left(Range("Table1[Dept1]") & "0000", 4)
Else 
    deptnum = Right(Range("Table1[Dept1]") & "0000", 4)
End If
```